# Showing pre-download processing at frontend

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I'll explain the **workflow** first -

1. User requests a download (jsp)
2. Based on user parameters(in spring mvc controller mapping), an excel workbook is first created my merging several other excel sheets (~40).
3. The final workbook is passed onto the front via FileInputSteam/PrintWriter.
4. Download starts.

**The problem** : The excel aggregation (step 2) sometimes takes 5+ minutes. So **is there a way**(other technology) **I can provide real time feedback to the user about the workbook creation process**, etc ? Currently, the browser just shows a loading sign unless the workbook is created and then throws a download pop up.

The technology stack I'm currently using : Java 1.5, Spring 3, jQuery 1.8.
App server : Apache Tomcat 6

Is Node.js a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Nope,

in my idea you can try to do something like this.

1. user click on download button.
2. ajax send request to prepare file.
3. for i = 0 to i < 5min do ajax request to check if file is ready.
4. when file is ready send it to user by simply redirect ;-)

Its background processing ;-)

good luck & have fun

Comment: Checking if a file is ready or not is not my requirement. Providing user real time feedback on file creation is. Something like 0.. 100 %.

Comment: "is ready or not is not my requirement" != "feedback on file creation is"